# NodeJS Express and Apache on same server

Tags: node.js, apache, express

I have a VPS with multiple virtural hosts specified in Apache config (/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf).

```
#Example config
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect / https://example.com/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub.example
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, I have Nodejs app on same server running with port *:3000. The problem is, that some ISP blocks that port and user can't use the app (e.g. in my school I can't access to this port). I want to that this app will run on port *:443, but I still want to use Apache to others host. Is there any way how to have app on same port as Apache and use that app only if user visit domain https://socket.example.com, otherwise it will use Apache. I'm adding example config of my Apache server and part of nodejs app.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/socket.example.com/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/socket.example.com/cert.pem', 'utf8');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 3000;
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);


httpsServer.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server running on port: ' + port);
});


var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type');

    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
    } else {
        next();
    }
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send(400);
    console.log("visit");
});
```

If I forgot about something just let me know and I will add it.

Comment: run node.js on a different port, and proxy request to node.js from apache.
check  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

Comment: I will look at that, but i google it before and found this solution, but it works when I enter e.g. "/node" after any domain and I want connect the app only if specific domain. And what means different port? Keep :3000 or?

Comment: Create a virtual host in Apache which will listen to port 443 and then proxy_pass request to the node.js application which you can run on port `3000`.

Answer (score 3):

Create an Apache virtual host which will proxy the request for a node.js application. you can run node.js application to any available port, and proxy it via apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName yourdomain.com
   ServerAlias www.yourdomain.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/defaultapp/
   Options -Indexes
   ErrorDocument 503 /check.html

   SSLProxyEngine On
   ProxyPass /check.html !
   ProxyPass / https://localhost:3000
   ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:3000
   ProxyPreserveHost On

   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.com.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.com.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.com:3000.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

Please check https://linuxtogether.org/configuring-reverse-proxy-for-node-using-apache-mod-proxy/ for details

Comment: Thank you for your advice, maybe it could be the solution that I have looking for, but with that config, the page display "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.". I tried to enable/disable some modules, add "Require all granted" to config bot nothing help me. Apache2 log: [Wed Jul 11 20:04:39.088714 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 3109] [client x] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: proxy:https://socket.example.com:3000

Comment: try running node.js application on http and serve https from apache. Also, make sure that  proxy and proxy_http module  are enabled ( to enable module `a2enmod proxy` `a2enmod proxy_http`)

Comment: both modules was enabled, tried to every solution that I found on stackoverflow, but most of them was about "Require all granted" which I tried before