# How can I run node and apache on the same server to allow the user to access api through https?

Tags: node.js, apache, express, deployment

I am running Node and Apache on the same server, where node is the backend server, requested by Axios to collect user data from the front end.

I used Apache to request an SSL certificate through `certbot` and was successful. I am trying to deploy node backend to access my `endpoint` ie `(website.com/endpoint)`.

I am able to see the test `index.html`, located in the website folder. When I try `aws.website.com/endpoint` I get the server time out and the 404 not found error.

The location of my app in the Linux server is `var/www/website.com` instead of the default `var/www/html` path.

My question: How can I run node and apache on the same server to allow the user to access the app through https?

***UPDATE: you need the node app to run on a separate port in my case 3001, and Apache to run on a separate port, ie 80, and use a reverse proxy via mod-proxy.

Here is the `000-default.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://18.191.235.31/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://18.191.235.31/
        ServerName aws.website.com
        ServerAdmin example@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/aws.backend-dg.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Here are my `config` files for the Apache virtual host:
`website/com.conf`:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerName aws.website.com
>     ...
>     DocumentRoot /var/www/aws.website.com
>     ...
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =aws.website.com
> RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

Here is my ‘website.com.le-ssl.conf’ (manually generated by certbot)`

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName aws.website.com
    ....
    DocumentRoot /var/www/aws.website.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/website/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/website/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Here is my `default-ssl.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            DocumentRoot /var/www/aws.backend-dg.com
            ....
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
            ....
            SSLEngine on
            ....
            SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
            ....
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

App.js file

```
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const logger = require("morgan");
const app = express();
require("./models/Email");
const routes = require("./routes/routes");

app.use(cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, PUT, GET, POST");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// Express only serves static assets in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}
app.get('*',(req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
app.use(express.json());
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use("/", routes);
app.use("/search", express.static("search"));

const mongoURI =
  "mongodb+srv://somename@cluster................";

const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);

mongoose.connect(
  mongoURI,
  { useNewUrlParser: true },
  { useUnifiedTopology: true }
);

conn.once("open", () => {
  console.log("Connection Successful");
});

conn.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:"));

 const server = app.listen(3001, () => {
 console.log(`Express running PORT ${server.address().port}`);
 });


const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const emailController = require('../controllers/EmailController');

router.get('/', emailController.baseRoute);
router.post('back/get-email', emailController.createEmail);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can you share your apache ssl conf? It should have some bindings for port 443...

Comment: So, your express app should be running on some port (e.g. 5005) and there should be a proxy_pass command in your apache ssl.conf...

Comment: @KemalKaplan I just updated my question with all config files. Regarding my express server, that is where my issue is, I can't use any other port than 443 to listen to, because of the SSL certificate on my domain. I have tried different ports ie: 444, 3000, 0, and so on, every time I try to make the express server live the connection and handshake is broken, the error is that the website is not secure: example https:aws.website.com:5000 gets me error, website is not secure

Comment: @KemalKaplan how do I write the prox cmd in the SSL conf?

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51290919/nodejs-express-and-apache-on-same-server

Comment: Could you please update the ssl config with your changes?

Comment: But you put the proxy pass commands ro http binding. You should also have them in the ssl config as well. And please check the slashes at the end of the command...

Comment: You should put it to le-ssl.conf. Please share the error messages. The best practice is to forward http to https. If you have slash at the first part of the proxy command then you should also have it at the second part as well.

Comment: For me since I am still new to Apache and proxy it would help others new and myself if you could kindly write an example of the correct code to forward from http to https and on what exact files. I shared all error messages on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69592715/run-node-and-apache-on-same-server-with-reverse-proxy

Comment: Ok, first you should not use https in proxy pass command, use http instead. And it is usually better to use 127.0.0.1 for proxy pass address which increases your performance.

Comment: Thank you for that information, I thought you had to use the instance IP address in the proxy pass? No?

Comment: If the apache and the node app runs on the same server, you can use local IP, o/w you should use the instance IP as you said...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to secure the node backend server in order for the user to stay on the secure `HTTPS` address. You do this by assigning `SSL` keys to the node server. Then edit the app.js file to connect to `HTTPS`, not `HTTP`. The above `app.js` connects to `HTTP` only. So this needed to be fixed. Finally, edit your reverse proxies in the `Apache` virtual hosts to fwd `HTTP` to `HTTPS`.

In my case, the frontend was secure via `HTTPS` `SSL` certificates from let's encrypt (`certbot`) ie `https://website.com`, but the backend was not secure, so when I tried to go to `https://websote/endpoint` there was an error.
The reason for this was because the backend `app.js` file connected to an `HTTP` server when it needed to connect to `HTTPS`.

**Note**: if you have a secure website/app and you make an Axios request to a non-secure `HTTP` address then you will get a `cors` error stating you need to change `HTTP` to `HTTPS`. You do this by making the node.js server secure.

### Here is the breakdown:

---

**1a**. Create a separate directory in the node folder to hold the certs.    `sudo mkdir directory_name`

**1b**. *Copy `SSL` certificates from the Apache server to the Node server directory.
`sudo cp etc/letsencrypt/live/your_webiste_folder/privkey.pem /var/www/directory_name`
`sudo cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/your_website_folder/fullchain.pem /var/www/directory_name`
*[click here for guide about copying files and its contents](https://www.linuxscrew.com/linux-cp-comman)*

**1c** Assign permission rules to that folder. I used `ubuntu` as my group because `root` had the ownership of the directory and the keys.
[*click this link to create a group and learn about permissions*](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/manage-permissions)
**-step a**. change ownership of group that owns the key files
-NOTE: you need to do this with `root`, type the following `cmd`: `sudo -i`
`chown group_name /var/path_to_webiste/cert_directory`
**-step b**. change ownership of keys in group
`chown group_name /var/path_to_website/privkey.pem`,
`chown group_name /var/path_to_website/fullchain.pem`,

**1d** Check to see if permissions were applied successfully
`ls -l`
-Below 3rd line is an example of permissions of directory to root
-Below 4th line is an example of permissions of directory to group_name (ubuntu). You want to see this line in your code.

> ```
> root@ip-123-45-67-890:/var/www# ls -l
> total 8
> drwxr-xr-x 6 root   root   4096 Oct 20 23:50 directory_name
> drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct 20 16:10 directory_name
> ```

[*Click here to learn more*](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions)

---

*2. Edit `app.js` or `server.js` to connect to `HTTPS` server, NOT `HTTP`*
**Note**: when you provide the location paths to the SSL certificates directories in the `Node` folder in `app.js` or `server.js`, `Node` will NOT be able to see them, this is why you need to assign permissions.

App.js:

```
   //imports
   ......
    
    //use node over secure server
    const https = require("https"),
        fs = require("fs");
    
    const sslServer =  https.createServer (
    {
      key: fs.readFileSync('/var/path_to_privkey.pem'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('/var/path_to_fullchain.pem'),
    },
    app  <---MAKE SURE TO PASS APP IN
    )
    
   ......
   ......
   
sslServer.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Express running PORT 3000 working!`)
});
```

[Click here for a walkthrough process for above app.js code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USrMdBF0zcg&t=621s)

3. Assign firewall permission rules to allow the `port` you are using from the `app.js` file ie `3001` to be allowed through the command `ufw`.
   -note: if you try to connect to the `port` and you get a timeout, then your firewall settings for apache are not allowing the port to come through, this is why you need to edit the apache firewall permissions
   `sudo ufw allow 3001`
4. Edit `000-default.conf`, `website.com.conf`, and `website.com-le-ssl` files to fwd from HTTP to HTTPS.
   -note: `website.com.conf-le-ssl` is generated by `certbot` from `letsencrypt`

000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName website.com
        ServerAlias www.website.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/website.com

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPass /get-email https://1.234.567.890:3001/
        ProxyPassReverse /get-email https://1.234.567.890:3001/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

website.com.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website.com
    ServerAlias www.website.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/aws.backend-dg.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://1.234.567.890:3001/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://1.234.567.890:3001/

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =aws.backend-dg.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =3.144.239.224:3001 [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =aws.backend-dg.com:3001 [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.aws.backend-dg.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

website.com-le-ssl.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName website.com
  ServerAlias www.website.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/website.com

  SSLProxyEngine On
  ProxyPass /get-email http://1.234.567.890:3001/
  ProxyPassReverse /get-email https://1.234.567.890:3001/
  ProxyPreserveHost Off
  ProxyRequests Off

  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```